# How to Find Default Accept-Charset/Accept-Encoding used by browser/webView android

Tags: android

I want to send an http request by adding the headers used by the browser

Accept-Encoding like  gzip, deflate

Accept-Charset like utf-8

how I can retrieve Accept-Encoding + Accept-Charset by using android sdk

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can retrieve the Accept-Encoding and Accept-Charset from android sdk. But you can use a packet sniffer (like wireshark) on the host where you run the emulator to find out the headers sent out by Android webview.

Here is what I found from Android ICS:

Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; google_sdk Build/MR1) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7

Hope that helps.